# ios app goes background when launched in ios9.3 after killed. but works fine in ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
Jan 23 09:34:06 ipad4 SpringBoard[46] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jan 23 09:34:06 ipad4 SpringBoard[46] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Jan 23 09:34:06 ipad4 kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[944] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B079D4E8-6E3B-4742-975F-F2FE38F78C1E (sandbox)
Jan 23 09:34:06 ipad4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: launchd + 85529 [083E000D-4C31-3B98-A2C4-6FADB4D1940F]: 0x3
Jan 23 09:34:07 ipad4 DealerApp[944] <Warning>: -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]:65 [Debug] Configured Web Service URL: \\\\\\\\\\
Jan 23 09:34:07 ipad4 DealerApp[944] <Warning>: Initializing  Manager Class!!!!!
Jan 23 09:34:07 ipad4 DealerApp[944] <Warning>: -[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]:147 [Debug] APP DELEGATE: applicationDidBecomeActive
Jan 23 09:34:26 ipad4 SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Forcing crash report of <FBApplicationProcess: 0x196f7ad0; DealerApp; pid: 944> (reason: 1, description: App failed to scene-create after 19.77s (launch took 0.23s of total time limit 20.00s))
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 syncdefaultsd[941] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x1556ab60>
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 ReportCrash[945] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: libsystem_trace.dylib + 15927 [E82A6F2D-873A-39AD-8014-EDEB52248157]: 0x0
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 Unknown[945] <Error>: 
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 ReportCrash[945] <Warning>: os_activity_diagnostic_for_pid() failed!
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Finished crash reporting.
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:—————[0x9b4][944]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:————[0x9b4]' exited abnormally via signal.
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 4288342351487: id=———pid=944, state=0
Jan 23 09:34:27 ipad4 ReportCrash[945] <Warning>: Saved type '109(109_DealerApp)' report (1 of max 25) at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DealerApp-2017-01-23-093427.ips
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Jan 23 09:34:07 ipad4 DealerApp[944] : Initializing Manager Class!!!!! 
Jan 23 09:34:07 ipad4 DealerApp[944] : -[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]:147 [Debug] APP DELEGATE: applicationDidBecomeActive 
Jan 23 09:34:26 ipad4 SpringBoard[46] : Forcing crash report of (reason: 1, description: App failed to scene-create after 19.77s (launch took 0.23s of total time limit 20.00s))
```

The first two lines show you were you've been and the last line told you why it crashed: the launch took too long. You would need to provide more context, e.g. the app delegate code to get an answer for why this is happening.

PS: Please use the code feature here, otherwise it's pretty hard to read

Comment: is there a way i send you the code in private. I don't know if am allowed to share the code here. thank you.